# Controlling the alpha value of plot symbols in a lattice densityplot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to use the **lattice** library's `densityplot` function to display some data. My data set is quite cluttered so I'd like to reduce the alpha value of the symbols plotted at the bottom (so you get a clearer view of in the case of overplotting). However, I can't seem to change the alpha value of just those symbols without making the actual density curve similarly opaque. I'm using the graph's `par.settings` options and setting different values for the `superpose.line` and `superpose.symbol` (and that works for changing the line types and symbols but not the alpha values for some reason). I've made a little example using the iris data set to illustrate my problem / current approach. If any one has any advice I'd really appreciate it.

```
library(lattice) 
data(iris) 

graph.settings <- list(superpose.line = list(lty = 1:3, lwd = 2, alpha = 1),
                       superpose.symbol = list(pch = 1:3, alpha = 0.3)) 
densityplot( ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris, groups = Species, 
            auto.key = list(columns = 3), aspect = 1, 
            main = "Density Plot of Sepal Lengths", xlab = "Length (mm)", 
            par.settings = graph.settings)
```

Comment: I don't know if this would have an impact on your situation, but under `?panel.superpose`, the alpha value is supposedly taken from the `superpose.line` alpha setting. However, examining the function `panel.superpose`, the alpha argument is given as `superpose.symbol$alpha`. Perhaps the package author could clarify.

Comment: I know this doesn't help in the short run, but at some point switching to `ggplot` may be a better approach.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I do use `ggplot2` for the majority of my other figures; in this case I prefer the look of the `lattice` version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. It works by supplying a 'custom' panel function, which calls `panel.densityplot()` twice: the first call gets you rug points with `alpha=0.3`; the second overplots density curves with `alpha=1`.

```
library(lattice) 
data(iris) 

graph.settings <- list(superpose.line = list(lty = 1:3, lwd = 2),
                       superpose.symbol = list(pch = 1:3)) 
densityplot( ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris, groups = Species, 
            auto.key = list(columns = 3), aspect = 1, 
            main = "Density Plot of Sepal Lengths", xlab = "Length (mm)", 
            par.settings = graph.settings,
            panel = function(x, ...) {
                panel.densityplot(x, ..., alpha = 0.3)
                panel.densityplot(x, ..., plot.points=FALSE, alpha = 1)
            })
```

Comment: Nicely done.  If the overplotting bugs you, you could also add `lty=0` in the first `panel.densityplot` call.

Comment: @Aaron -- It does bug *me* at least, so thanks for that clever tip.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien excellent, thanks, that does exactly what I wanted.